# How can I look up which server an application is running on?

Tags: networking, windows

A lot of times I will get a URL for an application that has some sort of problem.  In order to fix it I need to find out what server it's running on which usually involves running around and asking a few people.  Is there some way that I can look this up from the command line?  I tried NSLOOKUP but I think it only gives me the name server.

Comment: What type of application? What exactly are you asking 'a few people'(who?) to find out which server app has the issue?

Comment: Doesn't a URL by definition have the (domain) name of the server already??

Comment: @10, it's a web application.  I'm asking people who have knowledge of the application or network structure the following question, "Hey, what server is application-x running on".

Comment: @Chris - far from it. The front-end web server could be calling application logic *anywhere* - it could be a reverse-proxy Apache for tomcat on the same or a different machine, it could be calling a stored-procedure on a SQL box that is misbehaving, etc. Just because you know where the valet stand is doesn't mean you have any idea where your car is coming back from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL will often indicate where an application is running, e.g. "http://app01.somecompany.com/my/app" is running on "app01", but if your servers are load-balanced that may not be the case.

In cases where the URL isn't revealing you may get lucky and have your system designed in such a way that it discloses which server an application is running on (HTTP headers, `<META>` tags in the output, a status message sent to a client, etc.), otherwie you're pretty much down to asking around and **compiling documentation** as to which servers do what.

Comment: Yes! Unless your team/company/entity/institution/club has a standard naming policy or something, there's no way for you to know without documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Find it in your CMDB :-)

It is the best general answer. If your response is "What's that?" or "We don't have one", it's time to start building it - as voretaq7 said. If the answers are all only in other people's heads, start writing their answers down.